# PHP Login with Username/Password

Tags: php, arrays, session, authentication

How would I edit the PHP below to allow for additional or multiple user names and passwords.  For example User1 with Password JHFDE3, User2 with Password LKFW34, etc.  From what I have read, an associative array would likely be best.  There is no database, it is hardcoded to simply login and be able to view a php page.

For the particular code below, how would I make it into an associative array?  Thank you.

```
<?php
session_start(); //initiates the sessions
if ($_POST['submit']) //checks to make sure the login form has been submitted
    {
    $user = "XXXXX";
    $pass = "XXXXXXX";
    if ($_POST['pass'] == $pass && $_POST['user'] == $user) //checks if the password submitted by the user matches the password stored in the $pass variable
        {
        $_SESSION['access'] = 1; //if login is successful create a session that can be authenticated 
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); //reload the page. The page will now not load the login form (see the first if condition)
    } else //if password is incorrect reload the login form
        {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
} else if (!$_SESSION['access']) //if the "access" session is not accessible show the form (not logged in)
    {
?>
```

Comment: So this code works with a single user...but it's working code, right?

Comment: In general, we welcome questions that give the stated problem a go first - you can search for "associative array" on the PHP manual site. You'll need a `foreach` too. That said, you really _should_ user a database - maybe http://usercake.com/ would be of use? I've not used it, but it seems to get mentioned a fair bit around here.

Comment: if this is not a student assignment, hard coding passwords is a bad idea.

Even if it is an assignment, it is setting up bad habits.

Comment: @Robert - Yes it currently works. halfer cool ty, I will take a look at usercake.  Steve Yes, you're right I agree. I will hopefully add other ways to protect the pass with php, etc ty.

Comment: There is no need or a foreach...just a simple in_array call ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

--------------------------UPDATE----------------------------------

```
<?php
session_start(); //initiates the sessions

//begin testing
$_POST['user'] = 'username1';
$_POST['submit'] = true;
$_POST['password'] = 'pass3';
//end  testing

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) //checks to make sure the login form has been submitted
    {

    $users = array('username1','username2','username3');
    $passwords = array('pass1','pass2','pass3' );
    if(in_array($_POST['user'], $users))
    {
       $key = array_search($_POST['user'], $users);

       if($passwords[$key]==$_POST['password'])
       {
         $_SESSION['access'] = 1; //if login is successful create a session that can be authenticated 
         //header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
         echo "welcome back ".$_POST['user'];
       } else //if password is incorrect reload the login form
        {
         //header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
          echo "Password incorrect, error, redirecting to login";
        }


    }

    }
else 
{
  echo "Login form";
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Password incorrect, error, redirecting to login
```

But if you change the value of $_POST['password'] to  'pass1', like this:

```
$_POST['password'] = 'pass1';
```

You have this output:

```
welcome back username1
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.  Nice work.  However it does produce error(s) when I implemented your code.  I double checked any possible typos, read what I could about an in_array call, etc and still could not find why it produces a PHP error.  For reference, I am using a default PHP Version 5.2.17.  Any other suggestions would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Robert – Thank you SO much.  Your patience and knowledge solved the issue.  I can create several users, each with their own password.  After your first suggestion, I was having an issue (error) that was also causing the session to not be set, e.g. page reload prompted login.  I have addressed this and now, with your help, it works perfect.  Thank you again.  If you would like see the code in its entirety just let me know.

Thank you to others who also contributed. ;)

Comment: Send me the code to robert.rozas.n@gmail.com, in that way i can help you to improve it...i'm glad to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

if it is only two users that should not be hard to get around, you can do something as follows;

```
 <?php
//change the variable values accordingly
$user1='user1';
$user2='user2';
$pass1='pass1';
$pass2='pass2';
if ($_POST['submit'])  {
//check if they are equal to your info
if(($_POST['user']==$user1) && $_POST['pass'] == $pass1){
        $_SESSION['access'] = 1; 
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
} else if(($_POST['user']==$user2) && $_POST['pass'] == $pass2){
        $_SESSION['access'] = 1; 
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); 
} else {//not valid at all
//do what you want for login fail
}

}
?>
```